# How to create a pointer/pass parameter to function in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers

I am struggling to find the answer for this simply because I am unsure what to search for.

In objective-C I would do something like this to get a pointer to an object of a specific class:

```
CustomLabelClass *detailLabel = (CustomLabelClass *)[sortCell.contentView viewWithTag:kSortDetailLabelTag];
```

I would like to do the same in Swift. Basically I detect collision in Sprite Kit Scene and then try and pass the Node (which I know is of a specific class to another function).

```
    if ((contact.bodyA.node?.isKindOfClass(TapCircleIcon)) != nil) {
        updateOnScreenStatusFor(...)
```

I need to pass the TapCircleIcon into the function replacing '...'. So in Obj-c I would do something like:

```
TapCircleIcon *tapCircle = (TapCircleIcon *)[contact.bodyA.node];
```

Comment: So basically, a cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need `isKindOfClass` in Swift. I am assuming that `node` is an `AnyObject?` optional. You can cast it to `TapCircleIcon` and unwrap the optional using this if statement.

```
if let tapCircleIcon = contact.bodyA.node as? TapCircleIcon {
    updateOnScreenStatusFor(tapCircleIcon)
} else {
    // node is not a TapCircleIcon
}
```

Comment: It's an SKNode from collision. So does the same apply?

Comment: Is TapCircleIcon a subclass of SKNode? If it isn't, SKNode cannot be casted to TapCircleIcon.

Comment: Yes tapcricleicon is subclass of SKNode

Comment: Basically this is a failable cast. If the `node as? TapCircleIcon` fails to cast node to TapCircleIcon class, then the else statement will be called. If it is successful, then it will call `updateOnScreenStatusFor()`. This should be safe coding regardless of what node is.